# I can't get this function for creating strings from file

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

#define ODIT "log_file.txt"
#define INVENTORY_N "inventory_names.txt"
#define INVENTORY_A "inventory_amount.txt"
#define CURR_DIR "main-2dynamic"

static int inventory_amount_array[MAX_SIZE];
static char inventory_names_array[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];

void print_avail_opt(){
    printf("1) Read from the log file\n");
    printf("2) Save the current inventory in the log file\n");
    printf("3) Print current inventory item amounts\n");
    printf("4) Print current inventory item names\n");
    printf("5) Exit\n");

}

void get_inventory_int(){
    int i,n;
    char *token;
    char help[256];
    FILE *InputFile;
    InputFile = fopen(INVENTORY_A, "r");
    fscanf(InputFile, "%s", help);
    token = strtok(help, ",");
    i = 0;
    while(token != NULL){
        inventory_amount_array[i] = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        i++;
    }
    n = i;
}

void get_inventory_string(){
    int i,n;
    char *token;
    char help[256];
    FILE *InputFile;
    InputFile = fopen(INVENTORY_A, "r");
    fscanf(InputFile, "%s", help);
    token = strtok(help, ",");
    i = 0;
    while(token != NULL){
        inventory_names_array[i][i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        i++;
    }
    n = i;
}

void print_inventory_int(){
    int n = 10;
    get_inventory_int();
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        if( inventory_amount_array[i] == '\0'){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("Available stock from item:%d\n",inventory_amount_array[i]);
        }
        
    }
}

void print_inventory_string(){
    int n = 10;
    get_inventory_string();
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        if(inventory_names_array[i][i] == '\0'){
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("Available stock from %s\n",inventory_names_array[i]);
        }
    }
}

void f_print_inventory_int(FILE * log_file){
    int n;
    get_inventory_int();
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        if( inventory_amount_array[i] == '\0'){
            break;
        }
        else{
            fprintf(log_file,"%d ",inventory_amount_array[i]);
        }
        
    }
}

int read_from_file(FILE * log_file){
    log_file = fopen(ODIT, "r");
    char str[MAX_SIZE]; 

    while(fscanf(log_file,"%s", str)!=EOF){
        printf("%s", str);
    }
 
    fclose(log_file);

}

int write_in_file(FILE * log_file, int tm_year, int tm_mon, int tm_mday,int tm_hour, int tm_min, int tm_sec){
    log_file = fopen(ODIT, "a");
    

    fprintf(log_file,"\nInventory at %02d.%02d.%02d - %02d:%02d:%02d\n", tm_mday, tm_mon, tm_year, tm_hour, tm_min,tm_sec);
    f_print_inventory_int(log_file);
    
    fclose(log_file);

}

int restock (){

}

int main(){

    time_t T = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&T);

    FILE * log_file;

    bool loop = true;
    while (loop == true){

        print_avail_opt();

        printf("Enter op:");
        int op = 0;scanf("%d", &op);

        switch (op){
        case 1: read_from_file(log_file);
            break;
        case 2: write_in_file(log_file, tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
            break;
        case 3: print_inventory_int();
            break;
        case 4: print_inventory_string();
            break;
        case 5: loop = false;
            break;
        default: printf("Not correct option\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**I want to make case 4 in the main switch to work properly**

The things that are not working are the way of creating strings arrays and printing it out - everything else works fine.

*PS: And i would really appreciate a working functions, because i have it for homework at school and it's due tomorrow.*

*Note from my compiler (gcc):*

```c
main.c: In function ‘get_inventory_string’:
main.c:57:37: warning: assignment to ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   57 |         inventory_names_array[i][i] = token;
      |
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is warning you that you are assigning a `char*` pointer to a single `char` value in this statement:

```
inventory_names_array[i][i] = token;
```

That is not what you want or need.  You need to *copy* the characters pointed at by `token` into the array. You can use `strncpy()` for that:

```
strncpy(inventory_names_array[i], token, MAX_SIZE);
```

---

That being said, there are other problems with your code:

- not checking `fopen()` for failure.
- not closing opened files with `fclose()`.
- not preventing buffer overflows.
- your `get` functions are not storing `n` anywhere that your `print` function can reach, so you end up looping through the arrays using *incorrect* counts.  You should have the `get` functions `return` the actual array counts to the caller.
- `read_from_file()` and `write_in_file()` both take in a `FILE*` parameter that they don't use. Also, they are declared as returning an `int`, but they don't actually `return` anything.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100

#define ODIT "log_file.txt"
#define INVENTORY_N "inventory_names.txt"
#define INVENTORY_A "inventory_amount.txt"
#define CURR_DIR "main-2dynamic"

static int inventory_amount_array[MAX_SIZE];
static char inventory_names_array[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];

void print_avail_opt(){
    printf("1) Read from the log file\n");
    printf("2) Save the current inventory in the log file\n");
    printf("3) Print current inventory item amounts\n");
    printf("4) Print current inventory item names\n");
    printf("5) Exit\n")
}

int get_inventory_int(){
    int i = 0;
    char help[256];
    FILE *InputFile = fopen(INVENTORY_A, "r");
    if (InputFile == NULL) return 0;
    fscanf(InputFile, "%255s", help);
    fclose(InputFile);
    char *token = strtok(help, ",");
    while (token != NULL && i < MAX_SIZE){
        inventory_amount_array[i] = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

int get_inventory_string(){
    int i = 0;
    char help[256];
    FILE *InputFile = fopen(INVENTORY_A, "r");
    if (InputFile == NULL) return 0;
    fscanf(InputFile, "%255s", help);
    fclose(InputFile);
    char *token = strtok(help, ",");
    while (token != NULL && i < MAX_SIZE){
        strncpy(inventory_names_array[i], token, MAX_SIZE);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

void print_inventory_int(){
    int n = get_inventory_int();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        if (inventory_amount_array[i] == 0){
            break;
        }
        printf("Available stock from item: %d\n", inventory_amount_array[i]);
    }
}

void print_inventory_string(){
    int n = get_inventory_string();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        if (inventory_names_array[i][i] == '\0'){
            break;
        }
        printf("Available stock from %s\n", inventory_names_array[i]);
    }
}

void f_print_inventory_int(FILE * log_file){
    int n = get_inventory_int();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        if (inventory_amount_array[i] != 0){
            fprintf(log_file, "%d ", inventory_amount_array[i]);
        }
    }
}

void read_from_file(){
    FILE *log_file = fopen(ODIT, "r");
    if (log_file == NULL) return;

    char str[MAX_SIZE];
    while (fscanf(log_file, "%99s", str) == 1){
        printf("%s", str);
    }
 
    fclose(log_file);
}

void write_in_file(int tm_year, int tm_mon, int tm_mday, int tm_hour, int tm_min, int tm_sec){
    FILE *log_file = fopen(ODIT, "a");
    if (log_file == NULL) return;
    
    fprintf(log_file, "\nInventory at %02d.%02d.%02d - %02d:%02d:%02d\n", tm_mday, tm_mon, tm_year, tm_hour, tm_min,tm_sec);
    f_print_inventory_int(log_file);
    
    fclose(log_file);
}

int main(){

    time_t T = time(NULL);
    struct tm tm = *localtime(&T);

    bool loop = true;
    while (loop){

        print_avail_opt();

        printf("Enter op:");
        int op = 0; scanf("%d", &op);

        switch (op){
            case 1:
                read_from_file();
                break;
            case 2:
                write_in_file(tm.tm_year + 1900, tm.tm_mon + 1, tm.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec);
                break;
            case 3:
                print_inventory_int();
                break;
            case 4:
                print_inventory_string();
                break;
            case 5:
                loop = false;
                break;
            default:
                printf("Not correct option\n");
                break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Its working, but its not getting the next strings. I've did it like this 
`void get_inventory_string(){

    int i,n;

    char *token;

    char help[256];

    FILE *InputFile;

    InputFile = fopen(INVENTORY_N, "r");

    fscanf(InputFile, "%s", help);

    token = strtok(help, ",");

    i = 0;

    strncpy(inventory_names_array[i], token, MAX_SIZE);

}`

Comment: @ДимитърМилчев I did not say to get rid of the loop, just to change the assignment *inside* the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Just as the compiler warning said, your error is here:

```
inventory_names_array[i][i] = token;
```

`inventory_names_array[i][i]` is a `char`; `token` is a pointer. You need to dereference the pointer (note: this will clear this error, but you have other problems in your code, too).

Comment: I guess so - im a newbie